# Check if an M2M relationship exists

Tags: django, django-models

Basically, I have two models, Profile and Event. The Profile has an ownedEvent M2M to the Event table. The model looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    eventList = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank="TRUE", null="TRUE", related_name='event_set+')
    ownedEvent = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank="TRUE", null="TRUE", related_name='owned_set')
```

On a webpage, I want to display one of two things depending on whether the event has an owner or not. The user looking at the page may not necessarily be the owner, so I just need to check if there is **someone** out there that owns the event. How would I check for this in my template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to know, given an `Event`, whether there are any `Profiles` associated with it in the `ownedEvent` M2M table. If that's right, you can just do the following in your view code:

```
is_owned = some_event.owned_set.exists()
```

and then pass `is_owned` to your template for conditional processing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I think you can do something like...

```
if profiles=Profile.objects.filter(ownedEvent=YOUREVENT):
    #What you want if it is owned
else:
    #What you want if it isn't owned
```